# htaccess rewrite rules for multiple domains (symfony 2 in subfolders)

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, subdirectory

straight to the point.

I have a web hosting with 2 domains pointing to the root directory of the hosting.
I have 2 seperate projects in the root directory both symfony2
I need to redirect the domains to the seperate directories using .htaccess.

My current .htaccess file in the root folder

```
    RewriteEngine On
    #www to non www
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301, L]

    #domain1
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?domain1\.com$ [NC]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !/domain1/web
    RewriteRule ^(.*) /domain1/web$1 [L]

    #domain2
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?domain2\.com$ [NC]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !/domain2/web
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /domain2/web$1 [L]
```

now when I type in domain1 in the adress bar. The project works correctly. What I get in the adress bar is: "domain1.com/domain1/web" And I'd like to get rid of the domain1/web part so that the functionality stays. Do I somehow use rewrite base? Or is there an other way for me to get my result? please help. Note that I'm not really used to working with .htaccess so please be gentle :)

Comment: So if try to get `domain1.com/xxx` you are redirected to `domain1.com/domain1/web/xxx`?

Comment: if I try type in anything other that domain1.com I get an error 500, and this sucks because I cant use any routes for symfony this way If I type in: `domain1.com/domain1/web/app_dev.php` or (the app.php) I get the url rewritten to `domain1.com/domain1/web` When I try to get a route to work for example:
`domain1.com/domain1/web/app.php/someroute' i get a 500 error

Comment: I can get to work routes by using the app_dev.php but not the app.php. This mean when I type in: http://domain1.com/domain1/web/app_dev.php/test